# Profiles in iframe

Tags: profile

I am trying to include a subscription form (civicrm profile) in a static html using an iframe. Using '&snippet=1' in the url I can remove all the irrelevant page parts.

Works good when loading and submitting except when there is an error: then the page reloads without the '&snippet=1' and so the full page of civicrm site is loaded ...

Is there any way to force the 'snippet=1' part or should I look at making a second site with a shared civicrm db to do this. I need the crm site to work properly and to have a theme but I could add a second site with a stripped theme.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please say what CMS you are using and what version of CiviCRM?

Comment: woopie hadn't noticed this reply. CiviCRM is on a drupal 7. The iframe should be implemented in a static site.

Comment: Would it not be easier just to embed the HTML snippet instead of an iframe?

Comment: I feel very stupid now... I have always worked with CiviCRM on site (with drupal), and I have no clue where to find documentation for 'using an html snippet' for a profile...

Comment: i don't know if it is an answer, but in a similar situation we created a theme that had no styling in it, that way the profile showed on the external site with no civicrm or drupal elements/styling just a white background

Comment: that was the other option I had in mind. But then we need to make a multi-domain stall. One with styling, one without... Wonder if it works OK

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I foundout: HTML snippets are available in profiles if you enable external profiles only (System settings > Misc...). Will give that a try. Not really an answer to the initial question but will probably be good enough.